# Video player in google daydream VR sdk

Tags: virtual-reality, google-vr, daydream

I am trying to render 2D video content using google VR SDK, I tried to refer the documentation regarding the video viewports given in the dev page but it seems obsolete and incomplete and the samples on the github do not give any reference on how to create 2D quads and how to render external texture on it, there is only 360 video sample available. any reference or help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Playing a video is pretty much easy using GoogleVR SDK. All you need to do is, take a quad objects (from 3D objects), drag the GvrVideoTexturePlayer script (from the downloaded SDK), and set the material of mesh as VideoMaterial (from the downloaded SDK). Now just select the type of video (Dash/HLS) and enter the URL, the video should play.

Make sure that you are testing on the device as the video won't play on emulator. For 360° videos, replace quad object with sphere, rest is same.